# Using IPreviewHandler to preview images

Tags: c++, com, ipreviewhandler

I am attempting to use `IPreviewHandler` to create a dll that can preview an image in the file preview pane. I am basing it off of:

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appshellintegration/RecipePreviewHandler

To boil down my current approach I am hard coding in the path to an image, loading it as a HBITMAP and sending it to the pane window via `SendMessage()`. This approach is causing the following issues:

- I am unable to resize HBITMAP without reloading it, this seems highly inefficient.
- I am unable to choose to change the path of the bitmap depending on which file I click on. I would ideally like to extract the file name and use that to determine a path to the bitmap in another folder of the same name.

If anyone knows or can guide me to a better approach please let me know. I would ideally like it to act like how VLC treats its preview panes with an image previewing the video alongside the software's logo.

=========================EDIT============================

Here is how I have implemented the above:

Starting with `loadPreview()` which loads the bitmap.

```cpp
    boolean CRecipePreviewHandler::loadPreview
        (
        void
        )
    //*Description
    // change the bitmap control part of this to show the preview
    // from the file associated with m_bitmapFile
    {
        boolean r = TRUE;
        // Find dimension of bitmap
        std::ifstream file;
        file.open(m_bitmapFile, std::ios::binary);
        if (file.fail())
        {
            // File does not exist
            file.close();
            return r;
        }
        BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader;
        file.seekg(sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
        file.read((char*)&bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
        file.close();
        UINT cx = bmiHeader.biWidth;
        UINT cy = bmiHeader.biHeight;
        if (cx == 0 || cy == 0)
        {
            return r;
        }
    
    // transfer picture to dialog control
        m_b = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, m_bitmapFile, IMAGE_BITMAP, cx, cy, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        r = FALSE;
        return r;
    }
```

Where `m_b` is type `HBITMAP`, and `m_bitmapFile` is type `LPCWSTR` containing the path to the bitmap.

This is called by `DoPreview()`, an override from the `IPreviewHandler` class which sends the bitmap to the preview pane child window.

```cpp
HRESULT CRecipePreviewHandler::DoPreview()
{
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    if (_hwndPreview == NULL && _pStream) // cannot call more than once (Unload should be called before another DoPreview)
    {
        int border = 0;
        // Create the preview window
        _hwndPreview = CreateWindowExW(0, L"STATIC", NULL,
                                       SS_BITMAP | SS_CENTERIMAGE | SS_REALSIZECONTROL | WS_CHILDWINDOW,   // Always create read-only
                                       _rcParent.left+border, _rcParent.top+border, RECTWIDTH(_rcParent)+border, RECTHEIGHT(_rcParent)+border,
                                       _hwndParent, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (_hwndPreview == NULL)
        {
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        }
        else
        {
            if (loadPreview())
            {
                hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
            }
            else
            {
                SendMessage(_hwndPreview, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)m_b);
                ShowWindow(_hwndPreview, SW_SHOW);
            }
        }
    }
    return hr;
}
```

The rest of the code is fairly standard with an initializer, an uninitializer and a rectangle size setter (I am currently not changing the size of the bitmap due to the high cost).

Comment: It's far from clear what problem you have w/o a single line of code, why do you hardcode things, paths, etc. Please provide some reproducing project https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier I have added the code as requested. The question is more geared towards asking for the correct way of using preview handler for image previews as opposed to asking for a specific fix, hence why I initially didn't deem it necessary.

Comment: @SimonMourier I have currently hardcoded the path for testing purposes only. I intend on previewing an image that is contained in a folder with the same name and path of the currently selected file, therefore if I get the file path I can manipulate the string to retrieve the appropriate path. Alternatively the bitmap is also zipped within the file I want to preview so if I can directly extract it from there that would be very helpful.